# Would a restaurant name of "Punjab House" be offensive?

Tags: offensive-language, names

We are looking for a good name for an Indian restaurant that specializes in Punjabi food.  We have heard that naming the restaurant "Punjab House" would be offensive.

What specifically makes it inappropriate or offensive?  I was told it is a derogatory reference, but I don't see examples of that anywhere.

I'm specifically asking for any ways that it may be taken offensively, or any explanations why it would be regarded as an offense.

Comment: There's one such in Balham (South London) and Dundalk (Ireland), so opinion appears to be divided.

Comment: Why would "Punjab House" be offensive?

Comment: Voting to close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Yeah, I'm wondering how that would be offensive. Is it the dropping of the 'i'? Is it mentioning a region of India? 'house'?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because (1) it is not about English language & usage, and (2) it is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: I would edit out the request for suggesting a more appropriate name for this restaurant, which is highly subjective and dependent on personal taste i.e. "opinion-based". Your real concern is whether *Punjab* could be accused of being racist, based on prejudice, a clichè, stereotype etc. But again the answers you receive might be based on pure subjectivity, and have little to do with "language" as such.

Comment: For what it's worth, Google finds businesses called "Punjab House" in Pindi Point [Pakistan] (resort), Lahore [Pakistan] (clothing), Ernakulum [India] (restaurant), Jabalpur [India] (heliport lighting systems), London (restaurant), Dundalk [Ireland] (restaurant), Hong Kong (tailoring), and Sydney [Australia] (restaurant),

Comment: So far there are three people who have voted to reopen your question. Perhaps if you were to ask if the expression *Punjab House* has or has ever had a history of negative or derogatory connotations in the UK/USA. Or if English native speakers would consider the name a bit of a cliché or taboo? Take a look at the type of questions tagged pejorative-language http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pejorative-language; they might be a source of inspiration. Good luck!

Comment: What a pun job, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: OVEN]
Sikhs have five articles of faith natively known as Kakaars or Five K's. The articles include Kesh (uncut hair), Kanga (comb), Kara (Bracelet), Kirpan (sword) and Kachehra (a special type of shorts). A baptized Sikh is to wear all five articles of faith. These articles are not merely symbols, they not only represent or identify a Sikh but also have deep meanings.

Further at: [realsikhism.com](http://www.realsikhism.com/?subaction=showfull&id=1193703788&ucat=5)
and [BBC 19264843](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-birmingham-19264843)

My advice is not to use the Five K's, or names of Sikh Gurus, or their pictures in the name or logo for a restaurant.

Also, Punjab House is a (Punjab) government abode in New Delhi.

My Punjabi restaurant names : Flavors of Punjab , Punjabi Affaire, Punjabi Dhaba (Dhaba=a Punjab countryside food joint), Punjabi Tandoor (Tandoor = coal based Oven), Punjabi Junction.

For logoes you can take guidance from the images appended.

[image: Punjabi images![Oven]

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question, which doesn't mention any of the five K's. I guess, since the Punjabi government itself has an office in "Punjab House", that such a name isn't offensive.

Comment: From your answer I see how a logo may be offensive to some, if it were to trivialize the 5k's culture.  I also see how naming it after a government entity could make some feel uncomfortable.  I'm waiting to see if there are more examples.